# What is "readimg1"? is that a function in matlab?the distinction between readimg and readimg1?

Tags: matlab

I met the function when I read the code given by my senior classmates. she refused to tell me and let me search them on google. But I can't find the answer.

```
data = readimg1('G:\研究生\实验结果\实验\EDD ESD HR\师姐\数据\HR-shiyan\2018.09.17-DAY 9\A4-2_3D_000.IMG');
I = data(:,:,84);
```

Comment: It’s not a MATLAB function. Your friend may be trolling you, or maybe it’s part of the course material. MATLAB uses `imread` to read image files.

Comment: Yes, you are right.readimg1 is a function that is defined by my senior classmate herself. I was troubled by it all day.